# DriveApp.getFoldersByName give different result depending on user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a script that copies folders and content. It gets the folder names to copy from a sheet. All this works.
When the script comes to

```
DriveApp.getFoldersByName("NameOfFolder");
```

The script finds the folder iterator when I execute the script, but not when my colleague does.
If he does a search in Drive he can see the folder, the script returns `null`.
We have the same access to the folder. Its a shared folder on Google Drive.

Can anyone explain?

Here is the code that reproduces the error:

NB: the sheet supplies the script with propper names of folders to look for.

```
function shortTest() {
var episodeFolderList = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Folder name");
var episodeFolderByID = DriveApp.getFolderById("longFolderIDXXXXXXX");
Logger.log(episodeFolderByID+"-By ID")
var episodeFolder=episodeFolderList.next();
Logger.log (episodeFolder+ " -by name")

}
```

Ill ask him to log out of other accounts and try again.
Thank you for all the input.

Comment: Does your colleague get any error or a null value when using [`getFolderById`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid) with the same folder?

Comment: Have you checked sharing.  Since we can't reproduce the problem all we can go is guess.

Comment: Please add a [mcve], including but not limited to: if your colleague have signed in into multiple Google accounts, if they have already opened the folders, who are the owner of the folders and how those folders were shared with your colleague.

Comment: Thank you. Ill try if getFolderById Works. I have tried to do a short reproduciable script that gives the same result.

Comment: The share is owned by our Domain. Owner says our google domain name. Not an individual. We are both "Managers" of the folder.

Comment: It works with ID. However not with getFoldersByName, and he has logged out of all other google accounts.

Comment: -and another collueague with same credentials can excecute the script with no errors.

Comment: and i doulbe checked. He can do a search in google drive and find the folder by its name, so there is no reason why the script should not find anything.

Comment: @FernandoLara I fixed the script by changing the code to use getFolderByID, that i could retrieve from a link to the folder. But I didn't solve the problem of resolving getFoldersByName.

Comment: We tried to reset his authorisation and give permissinon again. That didn't change anything.

Comment: I would consider this a possible bug from Google Apps Script for this particular user. I recommend reporting this in [Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) so that someone at Google can check this problem, or you can also contact [Google Workspace Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en).